# How to “properly” yield in a Javascript worker for message processing?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, event-loop

In a Worker I need to yield regularly to allow the event loop to schedule incoming message processing.—At the moment I do that with a new promise and `setTimeout()`.

```
addEventListener('message', () => console.log('reading incoming message'));
async function work() {
    while (true) {
        // do a piece of work
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
        // break if ordered via message
    }
}
work();
```

Is there a compacter way to voluntarily yield processing?—It feels as if I’m missing something here: it looks like a super common task to do, but there is no “natural” way to do it?

Comment: Similar code as above, but await/promise split for less delay for re-entry, in case that is important: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62313956/825924

Answer (score 0):

You could use [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator), which are at least semantically clearer as to how the function behaves, but may not be "compacter" than your *async* function.
And to leave the control to the message queue, you can wait for an other message queue (i.e the one of a MessageChannel), which would be [faster than `setTimeout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61338780/is-there-a-faster-way-to-yield-to-javascript-event-loop-than-settimeout0/61339234#61339234).