# Can keyboardevent go any faster?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an autoclicker for a website but the auto clicker is only 400 cps I'm trying to see if it can go any faster

```
var event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{key:'g',
    ctrlKey:true
});

setInterval(function(){
   for(i=0; i< 100; i++){
     document.dispatchEvent(event);
   }
}, 0); 2256
256
```

Comment: and how do you check the speed?

Comment: the website shows cps

Comment: that's doesn't tell you how many cps you've sent out...

Comment: @BlueDuck you can try reverse for loop, maybe?

Comment: Make sure to declare your `var`iable `i` instead of implicitly creating a global

Comment: What happens if you choose a higher value than 100 for the number of iterations?

Comment: These events are fired synchronously, they don't go through the OS HID manager, they don't go through the USB bus, this code only measures how long it takes to execute the callback.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what website is capturing and how, but here is a little bench you can run:

```js
let sent = 0,
  received = 0,
  pack = 100,
  date = new Date().getTime(),
  stop = false,
  timer;

document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  if (++received > 1000000)
    stop = true;

  if (!(received % ((pack * 100 < 10000 ? pack *100 : 10000)))) {
    const time = (new Date().getTime() - date);
    console.log("sent:" + sent, "received:" + received, "Pack:" + pack, (pack * 100 < 10000 ? pack *100 : 10000), "Time:" + time, "CPS:" + ~~(received / time * 1000));
  }
});
var event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
  key: 'g',
  ctrlKey: true
});

function init()
{
  document.querySelector("button").textContent=stop?'START':'STOP';
  document.querySelector("select").value = pack;
  received = sent = 0;
  date = new Date().getTime();
  clearInterval(timer);
  if (stop)
    return;

  timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (stop)
      return init();

    for (let i = 0; i < pack; i++) {
      sent++;
      document.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
  }, 0);
}
init();
```

```html
<button onclick="stop=!stop;init()"></button>
<select oninput="pack=this.value;init()">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="100" selected>100</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="10000">10000</option>
  <option value="100000">100000</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I got around 24000 on a pretty good machine. I guess this isn't really a worry, and very machine dependent.

Comment: That only measures at which frequency setInterval(fn, 0) fires (4ms after the 5th call). You can have far higher rate by using a MessageChannel as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61338780/is-there-a-faster-way-to-yield-to-javascript-event-loop-than-settimeout0).  https://jsfiddle.net/bea61ypu/ But that misses the point. The events are fired synchronously, so if we remove the scheduling part, what this code would measure optimally is only the time taken to execute the callback.

Comment: Please read [answer] and always remember that you are not merely solving the problem at hand, but also educating the OP and any future readers of this question and answer. Thus, please [edit] the answer to include an explanation as to why it works.